# Convex Hull for Ternary plot using ggtern in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

## Polynators convex hull Area

Consider the following data.frame

```
DGChi <- structure(list(Sucrose = c(42, 40, 15, 19, 33, 49, 35, 31, 22, 
25, 37, 28, 31, 41, 27, 28, 33, 43, 21, 37, 14, 41, 30, 34, 38, 
40, 40, 33, 33), Fructose = c(27, 29, 41, 35, 29, 23, 27, 33, 
38, 38, 28, 31, 29, 26, 32, 34, 31, 28, 40, 30, 39, 27, 32, 31, 
29, 28, 28, 32, 29), Glucose = c(31, 31, 44, 46, 38, 28, 38, 
36, 40, 37, 35, 41, 40, 33, 41, 38, 36, 30, 39, 33, 47, 32, 38, 
35, 33, 32, 32, 35, 38), Sindrome = c("Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily")), .Names = c("Sucrose", 
"Fructose", "Glucose", "Sindrome"), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### First try

I am trying to make a ternary plot and add a convex hull around the points, my first try was using *geom_encircle* of the ggalt package:

```
library(ggtern)
library(ggalt)

ggtern(data = DGChi, aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose, fill = Sindrome)) +
theme_bw() +
geom_encircle(alpha=0.2,size=1, spread = 0.5) +
geom_point() +
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

With this result

[image]

Which encircles the points, but is not a convex hull

#### Second try using the geometry package

Trying to follow [my own answer for rgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145959/picture-convex-hull-in-3d-scatter-plot), I tried this:

```
library(geometry)
DGChiMin <- as.data.frame(convhulln(matrix(c(DGChi$Fructose, DGChi$Sucrose, DGChi$Glucose), ncol = 3)))
colnames(DGChiMin) <- c("Fructose", "Sucrose", "Glucose")
```

and then this for the plot:

```
ggtern(data = DGChi, aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = DGChiMin,aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

But got this super weird polygon:

[image]

Can someone help me get the convex hull plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you will find that geom_encircle uses chull internally. Set the expand parameter to 0.

```
library(ggalt)
library(ggtern)
ggtern(data = DGChi, aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose, fill = Sindrome)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_encircle(alpha=0.2,size=1, expand=0) + ##<<<<<< expand = 0
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution based on the `chull` function.

```
DGChi <- structure(list(Sucrose = c(42, 40, 15, 19, 33, 49, 35, 31, 22, 
25, 37, 28, 31, 41, 27, 28, 33, 43, 21, 37, 14, 41, 30, 34, 38, 
40, 40, 33, 33), Fructose = c(27, 29, 41, 35, 29, 23, 27, 33, 
38, 38, 28, 31, 29, 26, 32, 34, 31, 28, 40, 30, 39, 27, 32, 31, 
29, 28, 28, 32, 29), Glucose = c(31, 31, 44, 46, 38, 28, 38, 
36, 40, 37, 35, 41, 40, 33, 41, 38, 36, 30, 39, 33, 47, 32, 38, 
35, 33, 32, 32, 35, 38), Sindrome = c("Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", 
"Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily", "Chiropterophily")), .Names = c("Sucrose", 
"Fructose", "Glucose", "Sindrome"), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# Convex hull
ch <- chull(DGChi[,1:2])
DGChiMin <- DGChi[ch, 1:3]

library(ggtern)
ggtern(data = DGChi, aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose)) + geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = DGChiMin, aes(x = Fructose, y = Sucrose, z = Glucose), fill="#FF000044") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]